# Permanent While loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I have been struggling with my while loop and was wondering if you guys can see the fault in my logic.

**The concept of the project**

Creating a machine that will permanently loop through a bunch of code for the rest of its existence. Basically I am making an automatic cat feeder that will dispense food at certain times during the day. THAT IS WHY THE LOOP MUST BE PERMANENT.

**Here is my basic code so far:**

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");                                                                                    // 1.

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                                                                                                                      // 2.

    String CurrentTime  = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());                                                                                 // 3. 

    jTextArea2.setText(CurrentTime);


    String FeedTimeMorning              = "06:00";
    String FeedTimeSnack                = "19:07";
    String FeedTimeMidday               = "12:30";




    boolean TempFeed = false;


     while(TempFeed=false)

     {

     if (FeedTimeMorning.equals(CurrentTime)) { txaOne.setText("FeedCats"+" " +CurrentTime);}


     if (FeedTimeSnack.equals(CurrentTime)){txaOne.setText("FeedCats"+" " +CurrentTime);}


     if(FeedTimeMidday.equals(CurrentTime)){txaOne.setText("FeedCats"+" " +CurrentTime);}
```

When it comes to the designated time the text "Feed Cats " does not appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it has to be permanent then why not just loop infinitely? `while(true)`

Comment: `while(TempFeed==false)` or `while(true)` would work here.

Comment: Did not think of that.. Thanks man

Comment: Please read up on [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). It'll make your code much more readable.

Comment: Use `while(true)`. Writing `while(TempFeed==false)` is a quiet plea for re-education on coding standards.

Comment: Better to use sleep. Calculate time till next cat feed, then use sleep. Your loop will chew up a lot of CPU cycles just checking the time very often

Comment: Paulus, Haven't used the function. But what I can understand is, I can tell the sleep function to check lets say every half hour if the current time is this of the feeding time?

Comment: @TheNoobieCoder Even better (for that) might be a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks will definitely try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One equals (`=`) is assignment while two (`==`) is equality, this

```
while(TempFeed=false)
```

should be **one** of

```
while(TempFeed==false)
```

**or** the *shorter* `boolean` negation (omitting the `=` entirely) like

```
while(!TempFeed)
```

With one `=` it assigns `false` to `TempFeed` **and** evaluates to `false` (which means the loop is never entered).

Comment: @erickson Think I might have asked something similar to a question with an answer, Still appreciate the answers from everyone

Comment: @TheNoobieCoder I hope my answer helped; you might also have better luck with cron or (if you must use Java) [quartz scheduler](https://quartz-scheduler.org/).